# aSyncTask crashing on Nexus S but not Droid 1

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an aSyncTask used for a loading screen. In my doBackground, I  have

```
                    mCampusMap = (CampusMap) findViewById(R.id.CampusMap);      
                mCampusMap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to fire up my openGL View which takes 5 seconds or so to load.

Everything works fine on the Droid, but on a Nexus S i get the following error:

```
10-05 17:56:02.906: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(876): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the AsyncTask class inside your Activity class, try this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ((CampusMap) findViewById(R.id.CampusMap)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```